# Reporting on Activity Execution Time within an AWS Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions

Is there an established mechanism for reporting on activity performance with-in an AWS Step Function? I want to report on activity execution time for tasks with-in a state machine. I wanted a graph sort of like the following:

[image: demonstration graph]

I was reading through [Monitoring Step Functions Using CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-cw-metrics.html) but I didn't a clear picture of where this sort of data might live. That pushed me to look in CloudWatch, but I was only able to create dashboard widgets that visualized aggregated state machine execution time. I'd like it by activity with-in a state machine.

Comment: the Activity metrics only support the dimension `ActivityArn`. So you can't granularize that further. Not sure how feasible it may be to attempt creating [custom metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) for your use-case.